Can we say "outswim / outclimb / outslide" to mean "swim /climb/slide faster" the same way we say outrun?
In the dictionary

​outrun somebody/something to run faster or further than somebody/something
He couldn't outrun his pursuers.

Can we just invent words such as "outswim / outclimb / outslide" to mean "swim /climb/slide faster" the same way we say "outrun"?

Check a dictionary, some of these are standard.  Learners should be using standard words most of the time.

The only funny one is slide. Sliding is not a sport in English. Unless someone has invented it recently. You never know. sport de glisse is used in French and mean slide. Don't forget: to outdo

If the verb admits even the nose of degree into the tent, you can coin a new out-verb form. For example, since a person can be a light sleeper or a deep or heavy sleeper, or find it easy or difficult to fall asleep, someone could boast or marvel:

The dorm is noisy but he can outsleep anyone.

And since some singers are more talented than others:

She can outsing anyone.

But not all verbs admit degree.  It wouldn't work to say

He outsuccumbed his acquaintances during the plague. unidiomatic

The out prefix brings to the foreground how the verb admits degree, and if  there is nothing to be foregrounded, your coinage throws an error, so to speak.
Moreover, the out prefix has a positive spin, that is, the subject performs the verb to a greater degree.  So even if we can contrive a scenario where the verb occurs on a better...worse scale, out doesn't work when the meaning is "to a worse degree", even in cases where the verb expresses something negative, so that performing the verb's action to  a worse degree would be consonant with its meaning:

The new strain of hybrid corn outwithered the older strains during the drought. unidiomatic

But you could say it the other way around:

The older strains of corn outsurvived the new hybrid strain during the drought.


As a non-native speaker I cannot be certain, but I think all of those are ok, even if rarer than, say, outplay or outmanouver. Or even outsmart. In other words, this construct applies to mental as well as physical abilities.
May be stating that you will most definitely be understood would be a good way of phrasing my opinion?
